# when i use countDownLatch , the collection has a null element. why?

Tags: java

```
List<Object> objects = service.search(searchBo); //the list hasn't null element
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(objects)) {
List<Object> results = Lists.newArrayList();

CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(objects.size());
for (Object object : objects) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            String albumFileKey = albumService.getAlbumFileKey(object.getFileKey());
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(albumFileKey)) {
                object.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
                object.setAlbumFileKey(albumFileKey);
                results.add(object);
            }
            doneSignal.countDown();
        });
}
try {
    doneSignal.await();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    LOGGER.error("album service occur exception", exception);
}
```

the question:
the results has a null element, when i traverse the list ,then ocurr NPE. I wonder how did this null element get into the results list

Comment: you are creating an array list with a fixed size and you have an if clues that needs to be true to put values.
so if you have a null value the if returned false for one or more of your inputs.

Comment: `ArrayList` isn’t threadsafe. Try using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or a synchronized collection.

Comment: @Ofer Skulsky `results` is initialized to be empty with `Lists.newArrayList()`. Its size is not fixed and will only be increased if an object is successfully `add`ed.

Comment: @TimMoore but i can't reappear the error

Comment: The nature of thread safety problems is that they are not consistently reproducible. They happen because of small, uncontrolled timing differences.